# Redirect to page with non http/https protocol

Tags: tapestry

I need on open specific page redirect to specific url.

It's url seems (it's properly opened on android device):
`intent://details?id=...&url=https://...&referrer=...#Intent;scheme=market;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;package=com.android.vending;end`

I try return on `onActivate` with `new URL()`, but get error `unknown protocol intent`. Then I try return url as String, get error too.

How I can fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm create custom `URLStreamHandlerFactory` and set it by `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory`. Now I can create URL with my specific url